# Change ethX index

Tags: networking, kernel, udev

When I run `ifconfig` in one of my machine I saw these.

The Q is where does the index `eth3` and `eth4` from? Is there a way to change them to `eth0` and `eth1`?

```
$ ifconfig
eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1a:a0:9d:c9:90  
          inet addr:192.168.1.100  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fddc:2a53:4ad:0:a412:573:557c:ce58/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fddc:2a53:4ad:0:21a:a0ff:fe9d:c990/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::21a:a0ff:fe9d:c990/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: fddc:2a53:4ad::c68/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fddc:2a53:4ad:0:41f0:3be9:2668:e5b/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fddc:2a53:4ad:0:4daf:e298:e54c:2540/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:217764 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:402733 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:21329905 (21.3 MB)  TX bytes:40208000 (40.2 MB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:fdfc0000-fdfe0000 

eth4      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e8:94:f6:02:eb:a7  
          inet addr:192.168.0.108  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ea94:f6ff:fe02:eba7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2604292 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2069814 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:486616623 (486.6 MB)  TX bytes:472115888 (472.1 MB)
```

---

Edit1:

```
$ grep 'eth' /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:14:6c:72:d2:46", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:1e:c9:6c:8c:a3", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="30:b5:c2:03:46:4d", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth2"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:1a:a0:9d:c9:90", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth3"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="e8:94:f6:02:eb:a7", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth4"
```

(Yes I have two Eth cards, one 100 and the other 1000 Mbps).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `grep 'eth' /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`

Comment: I added the output of the command you suggested - thanks.

Comment: It shows you have three other Ethernet cards too..check with `ifconfig -a`

Comment: `ifconfig -a` shows only 02 Eth cards. Do I miss something?

Comment: Ok..if you want to rename the interfaces, put a `#` before the lines of `eth0`, `eth1` and `eth2` and then replace the `eth3` and `eth4` at last of the relevant lines in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` with `eth0` and `eth1` ..now restart `network-manager` or any other process you are using to manage the networking..then check the names..

Comment: Cool - just restarting `network-manager` doesn't change it. But after I reboot the machine, then as you said the ethX index has changed. I didn't know about that config file. Please convert your comment to an answer - thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The interface names are assigned by `udev` dynamically or according to the rules declared in the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`. Although `udev` manages devices dynamically, putting the rules in this file make `udev` to take persistent decisions about the interfaces defined here.

So to change the name of an interface, open the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`, find the appropriate interface first by checking the MAC address e.g. `ATTR{address}=="00:1a:XX:YY:c9:ZZ"`. After finding the interface you want to change the name, replace the name e.g. `NAME="eth3"` at last of the line with the name you want e.g. `NAME="eth0"`

So the line becomes :

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:1a:XX:YY:c9:ZZ", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

Also do the same for other interface rules too if you want to change their names too. After doing the renaming restart the computer and the interfaces should be renamed properly.

Also note that as you have interfaces defined already with names `eth0` and `eth1`, disable those rules by deleting or commenting out the lines containing the rules first, otherwise there will be a conflict and renaming won't be done.

Comment: Or `sudo service udev restart`? Would that be enough?

Comment: @A.B. Yeah..that should do too..in that case the service managing networking needs to be restarted too..

Answer (score 2):

I am  attempting to answer only one part : "Where does eth3 & eth4 came from ?. Going by one of my experience, the mac addresses pointing to the  names eth0,eth1, eth2 would have been become redundant by  a mother board/network card replacement in the machine. So if this caused by a network interface going away from the machine, you can safely delete them.